# how to detect failed windows logon

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, winapi

i'm looking for a code that detects failure to log in into windows.

i've looked into sens.dll (ISensLogon interface) and it provides only log on\off capabilities but not an event when incorrect logon was made.

thanks,
Zack

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145981/failed-logon-counter-for-local-users

Comment: it's not since the solution in your link require to test it with a specific user name. i want to know if logon failed for any user name. also notice that this solution require to check constantly for failures (in case im using this solution for the current user), don't windows have something with callback.... please upvote :)

Comment: Then you should edit the question to specify these extra conditions too. I didn't downvote you, by the way. ;-)

Comment: Ask ServerFault about configuring logon failure audits.  Or read [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch on the auditing of these events and query the security event log in you program.